# Insert query to mysql database from java not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a problem with following method. The method generate a valid query, but it cannot insert the table monitor.

The method:

```
public void upLoadData(String table, String[] dbCols,List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> values){
        String wq = "INSERT INTO "+table+" (";
        for (int j = 0; j < dbCols.length; j++) {
            wq+=dbCols[j]+",";
        }
        wq = wq.replaceAll(",$", ""); //Remove comma from the end of line.
        wq+=") VALUES";

        for (LinkedHashMap<String, String> val : values) {
            wq+="(";
            for (int i = 0; i < dbCols.length; i++) {
                wq+="'"+val.get(dbCols[i])+"',";
            }
            wq = wq.replaceAll(",$","");
            wq+="),";
        }
        wq = wq.replaceAll(",$", ";");

        System.out.println(wq);
        myDB.DBInsert(wq, MyDBPool.getConnections());
}
```

And the insert method:

```
public void DBInsert(String query, Connection conn){
    Statement stm;
    try{
        stm = conn.createStatement(); // conn from db connection pool
        stm.executeUpdate(query);
    }catch(SQLException ex){ex.getLocalizedMessage();}
}
```

The output is:

```
INSERT INTO monitor (id,arr_date,company,disp_size,disp_type,producer,prod_type,color,cond_cat,comments) 
VALUES('H13/2:3445','2015-11-15','Valami','jó','21','Dell','T32','fekete','B','sadsadasdasd'),
('H14:/3:5567','2015-11-15','Nincs','TFT','19','HP','B32','piros','A','sadsadasd'),
('H13/8:3321','2015-11-15','CCCP','CRT','19','nincs','T24','fehér','D','sadsadsad');
```

Manualy(PhPMyAdmin) insert is not problem.
I use JDBC, and Hikari dbpool, XAMPP v3.2.1

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Are you committing the insert ?

Comment: DB Pool use auto commit

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No, it seems to every thing is alright, no error message nor from mysql, java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't `commit`ing, and you aren't `close`ing your `Statement` (or `Connection`). You could use a [`try-with-resources` close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and add a `commit` like

```
public void DBInsert(String query, Connection conn) {
    try (Statement stm = conn.createStatement()){
        stm.executeUpdate(query);
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.getLocalizedMessage();
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I strongly recommend you use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and *`?` placeholder* (or *bind paramters*) for *performance* and *security reasons* instead of building your inserts as `String`.

Comment: Moreover I suggest to use StringBuilder/StringBuffer to construct the queries if you need to append any values.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working, I update my method as you adviced, change  Statement to  PreparedStatement, put placeholders, but no affect.
By the way I have another query that use the original insert method and it's work fine. Is there any opportunities the primary key of the table is disturb the insert task?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and advise, finally I found the problem, my old insert method is work fine(but I update and refact as Elliott Frisch advised), the problem is only I swap two columns with different types,so PhPMyAdmin is handle the error(give 0 to mismatch value), but Java JDBC cannot resolve, so drop the insert task.

Once more, Thanks a lot! :)